# How to get a child value in firebase with swift 3.0

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display a string of "1.0" on an UITextField by reading the AppVersion Key from firebase
My firebase JSON is simply the following

```
{
  "AppVersion" : "1.0"
}
```

My swift code (swift 3.0)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("AppVersion")
    AppVersionLabel.text = ref.key
}
```

The field display the word "AppVersion" instead of "1.0"

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an observer for the value.

```
ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  AppVersionLabel.text = snapshot.value as? String?
})
```

If you're only interested in the *current* version number (and not in receiving updates automatically), you can use `observeSingleEvent` with the same signature.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events